# Auto Suggest for very slow internet connections

Tags: e-commerce, mobile-website, javascript, autocomplete

I have an auto suggestion mechanism that works fairly nice for desktop version where we have a wireless or a wired internet connection. The worst response time is 320ms.
(Without using solr as of now, I use a storage system on the server that gives back the result).

I have users that belong to the group where you can have a slow internet connection also known as a 2G connection where the downspeed can be ~10Kbps-50Kbps.

I have seen that google provides Auto Suggestion to this speed as-well, my my system cannot.

I have tried these:

1. Make a txt and JSON file on the server and when the user does a keydown (1st) it fires ajax to bring the entire 2.2MB data inside a JS variable on client side and show suggestions.
2. Make a service that is called when the user types 2 characters, service reads the txt/JSON file for those 3 character occurence anywhere in the words and gives data into a JS variable.
3. Repeat the above step and store the result in localStorage, for a fresh 3 characters again the same process occurs and storage happens. The benefit is that the user in future gets a prompt suggestion but according to  me browser storage is used very sensibly.

Anyone with suggestions how www.google.com and www.flipkart.com handles auto suggestions for slow internet connections on mobile (smartphones).

Comment: @JonW Why? This has been the buzz in the search industry to maximize the UX..so why off the topic?

Comment: I have a very slow connection at home and can't say that Google's suggestions work fast. In fact, sometimes they don't appear at all, even 10 seconds after typing the first word. Your approach of caching the autosuggestion list on user's end is good and works fine for me on a similar service. In there, the list on my end is only updated every once in a while, so I don't have to wait for it to download on each visit.

Comment: This isn't a UX question because you've already decided what the User Experience answer is: you want to provide auto  suggest. What you're asking here is *how* to implement that UX solution, so you've moved on from the scope of this site at that point. We can help with *what* to implement, but *how* you implement it is out of scope here.

Comment: But i also work on the result relevancy depending on the location and other parameters before displaying auto suggestion on the desktop version, I will limit myself here by caching on mobile browser!